# Gcloud run service replace removes previous revision(s) prefix(s)

Tags: docker, yaml, google-cloud-run

Unexpected behaviour `gcloud run service replace` removes previous revision(s) prefix(s). How to persist the previous revision prefix(es) in service.yaml? Useful for controlling traffic to each of the deployments. For example, `prod---*` revision etc.

Answer (score 2):

This was happening because my `service.yaml` had the block:

```yaml
traffic:
  - latestRevision: true
    percent: 100
```

I needed to add this block [from the docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/rollouts-rollbacks-traffic-migration#yaml_4):

```yaml
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: SERVICE
spec:
...
  traffic:
  - revisionName: REVISION
    tag: TAG_NAME
    percent: PERCENT-NEW
  - revisionName: REVISION-FORMER
    percent: PERCENT-FORMER
```